# JavaScript prevent touch move on body element, enable on other elements

Tags: javascript, events, default, event-propagation, touchmove

but very simply, I'd like to prevent the touchmove event on the body element but leave it enabled for another element. I can disable fine... but I'm not sure how to re-enable it somewhere else!

I imagine that the below theoretically works because `return true` is the opposite of `preventDefault`, but it doesn't work for me. Might be 'cause `$altNav` element is *in* `$bod`?

JS:

```
$bod.bind('touchmove', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
});
$altNav.bind('touchmove', function(event){

    return true;
});
```

Comment: I think you're looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339190/undo-preventdefault-or-better-way-to-programmatically-disable-collections-of-l

Comment: @Mahan kind of sort of. I'm not un-binding $bod.. I'm just allowing it on $altNav. See what I mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what lib you're actually using, but I'll asume jQuery (I'll also post the same code in browser-native-js if you're using something other than jQ)

```
$bod.delegate('*', 'touchstart',function(e)
{
    if ($(this) !== $altNav)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        //and /or
        return false;
    }
    //current event target is $altNav, handle accordingly
});
```

That should take care of everything. The callback here deals with *all* touchmove events, and invokes the `preventDefault` method every time the event was triggered on an element *other* than `$altNav`.

In std browser-js, this code looks something like:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    //in case $altNav is a class:
    if (!target.className.match(/\baltNav\b/))
    {
        e.returnValue = false;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.preventDefault)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        return false;//or return e, doesn't matter
    }
    //target is a reference to an $altNav element here, e is the event object, go mad
},false);
```

Now, if `$altNav` is an element with a particular id, just replace the `target.className.match()` thing with `target.id === 'altNav'` and so on...
Good luck, hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom CSS class and test for it in the document handler, eg:

```
<div>
    This div and its parents cannot be scrolled.
    <div class="touch-moveable">
        This div and its children can.
    </div>
</div>
```

then:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'touchmove', function( ev )
{
    if (!jQuery( ev.target ).parents().hasClass( 'touch-moveable' ))
    {
         ev.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

http://tinyurl.com/mo6vwrq

Answer (score 1):

you can add a argument,like this

```
$bod.bind('touchmove', function(event,enable){
   if(enable){
       event.preventDefault();
   }

});
```